Use Pytorch LightGlue in Android app using Flutter
I struggle to get LightGlue working on Android. I thought because it is optimized for speed it would be the perfect target to try to learn more about building a Phone App but I cannot get it to work.
I only found sources on how to get a torchscript model working on android but not a pure pytorch model. So I tried to convert the model to torchscript with no success.
I tried:

torch.jit.trace(model, example) but the model seems to be heavily dependent on the input data and therefore tracing it breaks the moment I use different inputs.
torch.jit.script(model) but couldn't get it to work because it seems like every second line uses a feature that is incompatible with the script feature
torch.compile(model) worked for compiling but I have no idea how to save the compiled model or load it. So this one is also not working out

I am not dependent on flutter, so if you can recommend another framework I am happy to use it.
Any ideas how to get this working?
